# booting debian image via PXE boot gives No common CD-ROM drive detected

Tags: pxe-boot, debian-jessie, preseed

I have created a custom debian image which should be autoinstall itself using preseed. When I load the image via Dell idrac virtual drive everything goes smoothly, however if I am trying to serve the image trough PXE network boot I after the installer starts I get "No common CD-ROM drive detected" error message and the installation cannot continue. Any suggestion how to get this working?

Comment: Could you solve this?

Comment: Sorry no solution